# Highcharts Gauge - start/endAngle and height

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a gauge chart that is revered.
If i set charts `{ height : 300 }` and `{ startAngle: -76,endAngle: 234 }` i get a nice centered gauge.
But if i change `{ height : 400 }` start and end get all messed up and when i change them i get wierd results ...

This is with `{ height : 300 }`
http://jsfiddle.net/v2Tz6/2/

This is with `{ height : 400 }`
http://jsfiddle.net/v2Tz6/3/

Can someone please explane to me what is going on and how can i fix it ?

Also the start animation is messed up.Thats not so important,i guess i can just turn it of,but it would be nice to get a fix for that too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use reversed parameter and plotbands in dicreasing order.